# Denseness of the image of a certain continuous function from real line to the product of two copies of unit circles

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that $a/b$ is irrational . Consider the continuous function $f : \mathbb R \to S^1 \times S^1$ as $f(t)=(e^{2\pi iat } , e^{2\pi ibt}) , \forall t \in \mathbb R$ ; then is it true that $f(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $S^1 \times S^1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Taking $t_k=\frac kb$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, we obtain a set of points $f(t_k)$ dense in $S^1\times \{1\}$. With $u_k=\frac ka$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, we obtain a set of points $f(u_k)$ dense in $\{1\}\times S^1$. The combinations $f(t_k+u_m)$ are readily seen to be dense in $S^1\times S^1$.